# Merge pandas DataFrames by partial match in datetime column

Tags: python, pandas

Hello good people of stackoverflow. I can't quite grasp the solution here, so please, help me out. 
Please, keep in mind that I'm quite a beginner at python, so please, keep it as simple as you can.

My company provides employees with transportation to and from work. There is a system in place that tracks when employee got on the bus and which bus the person got onto. Also we receive data from transportation company with information where and when employees were supposed to go as per planning(every employee books the spot in advance). Sometimes people don't book places, sometimes they get onto the wrong bus(not the route they booked) or at the wrong time. My goal is to find such people and provide a report.

Here is the sample of the data we receive from the transportation company

```
IDs     DepartureTime               Destination
13519   2019-12-15 16:15:00.000000  100 DefaultCity
10977   2019-12-15 16:15:00.000000  200 DefaultCity_2
13329   2019-12-15 16:15:00.000000  300 DefaultCity_3
14597   2019-12-16 16:15:00.000000  200 DefaultCity_2
16899   2019-12-16 16:15:00.000000  400 DefaultCity_4
14616   2019-12-16 16:15:00.000000  300 DefaultCity_3
12519   2019-12-17 16:15:00.000000  800 DefaultCity_8
11347   2019-12-17 16:15:00.000000  200 DefaultCity_2
```

Here is the sample of the factual data we receive from tracking system

```
EmployeeID     DepartureTime                Destination
3027199        2019-12-15 16:12:53.000000   800 DefaultCity_8
3022569        2019-12-15 19:11:24.000000   200 DefaultCity_2
3672468        2019-12-15 16:22:46.000000   300 DefaultCity_3
3027419        2019-12-16 16:12:53.000000   800 DefaultCity_8
3045129        2019-12-16 16:11:24.000000   400 DefaultCity_4
3869438        2019-12-16 16:22:46.000000   300 DefaultCity_3
3487645        2019-12-17 16:12:53.000000   800 DefaultCity_8
3345935        2019-12-17 19:11:24.000000   200 DefaultCity_2
3235128        2019-12-17 16:22:46.000000   300 DefaultCity_3
```

Also I have an SQL table that helps me bind IDs to EmployeeID

```
EmployeeID     name                  IDs
3027199        Alice Doe             13519  
3022569        Bob Doe               10977  
3672468        Karl Doe              13329  
3027419        Mark Doe              14597  
3045129        Jenna Doe             16899  
3869438        Victoria Doe          14616 
3487645        Vladimir Doe          12519  
3345935        Kenny Doe             11347  
3235128        Heather Doe           14403
```

It is worth mentioning that "planned" data is present for every working date, but "factual" is not, since company only performs spontaneous spot checks.

What did I manage:

1. Filter "planned data" and "factual" within a certain date range by using pyjanitor+pandas and df.filter_date function
2. Merge Names, Ids and EmployeeIDs

What I'm struggling to do:

1. Merge "planned" with "factual" without including dates present in "planned" but absent in "factual"
2. Actually find the people by mismatch in time/Destination between "planned and "factual" data. Please, note that I want to consider time frame, say 16:01 - 16:29 as 16:15 when comparing "planned" and "factual" and show only people who got onto the bus at different hour.
3. Find people who didn't book at all. There will be no data in "planned" regarding them at all, but there will be in "factual"

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpSzT.png)

I'll be glad to provide you with any additional info that may help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your input data(more rows) & the expected output for that data?

Comment: @moys Added additional data as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as follows.

In the code below, the first df is named as `df_booking`,the second df is named as `df_actual` & the SQL database as `df_info`.

```
df_booking.rename(columns={'DepartureTime':'DepartureTime_booking', 'Destination':'Destination_booking'}, inplace=True)
df_booking = df_booking.merge(df_info, on='IDs')

df_actual.rename(columns={'DepartureTime':'DepartureTime_actual', 'Destination':'Destination_actual'}, inplace=True)
df_actual = df_actual.merge(df_info, on='EmployeeID')

df_anomoly = df_actual.merge(df_booking, on='EmployeeID', how = 'inner',suffixes=('', '_y') )
df_anomoly['diff_dest'] = np.where(df_anomoly['Destination_actual'].str.extract('(\d+)')!=df_anomoly['Destination_booking'].str.extract('(\d+)'),'Yes','No')
df_anomoly['diff_time']=np.where(pd.to_datetime(df_anomoly['DepartureTime_actual']).dt.floor("30min")!=pd.to_datetime(df_anomoly['DepartureTime_booking']).dt.floor("30min"),'Yes','No')
df_anomoly.drop(list(df_anomoly.filter(regex='_y$')), axis=1, inplace=True)
df_anomoly
print(df_anomoly)
```

**Output**

```
EmployeeID  DepartureTime_actual    Destination_actual  name    IDs     DepartureTime_booking   Destination_booking     diff_dest   diff_time
0   3027199     12/15/2019 16:12    800 DefaultCity_8   Alice Doe   13519   12/15/2019 16:15    100 DefaultCity     Yes     No
1   3022569     12/15/2019 19:11    200 DefaultCity_2   Bob Doe     10977   12/15/2019 16:15    200 DefaultCity_2   No  Yes
2   3672468     12/15/2019 16:22    300 DefaultCity_3   Karl Doe    13329   12/15/2019 16:15    300 DefaultCity_3   No  No
3   3027419     12/16/2019 16:12    800 DefaultCity_8   Mark Doe    14597   12/16/2019 16:15    200 DefaultCity_2   Yes     No
4   3045129     12/16/2019 16:11    400 DefaultCity_4   Jenna Doe   16899   12/16/2019 16:15    400 DefaultCity_4   No  No
5   3869438     12/16/2019 16:22    300 DefaultCity_3   Victoria Doe    14616   12/16/2019 16:15    300 DefaultCity_3   No  No
6   3487645     12/17/2019 16:12    800 DefaultCity_8   Vladimir Doe    12519   12/17/2019 16:15    800 DefaultCity_8   No  No
7   3345935     12/17/2019 19:11    200 DefaultCity_2   Kenny Doe   11347   12/17/2019 16:15    200 DefaultCity_2   No  Yes
```

Comment: Then use `inner` instead of `outer`in the code `df_anomoly = df_actual.merge(df_booking, on='EmployeeID', how = 'outer',suffixes=('', '_y') )`

Comment: even with inner I'm still getting incorrect output.
[link](https://imgur.com/YCJkBOn)
This is what I was talking about the data that is present in booking but absent in actual, because that day check was not performed. Maybe it has something to do with how I select the date range.
df_booking = df_booking.filter_date('DepartureTime', date_from, date_to)
df_actual = df_actual.filter_date('DepartureTime', date_from, date_to)
to get this output I selected timerange from 2019-12-15 to today.

Comment: Create a column 'Date' in both dataframe with `pd.to_datetime(df_anomoly['DepartureTime_actual']).dt.date` and in the end use that to merge like so `df_actual.merge(df_booking, on=['EmployeeID', 'Date'] how = 'inner',suffixes=('', '_y') ` This will only mege values based on Employee ID's & dates that are in the `df_actual` dataframe

Comment: Now it works fully! Thank you a lot, I was trying to wrap my head around it for a week. In your code I found quite a few things I have no idea about, I'll need to sit and figure everything out step by step. Thank you again.

Comment: If the answer helped consider up-voting & accepting it.

Comment: Just did some tests on actual data and noticed that this code doesn't include those, who didn't book but went.

Comment: They should. We may just have to create a column to identify those specifically. Update your input to cover this scenario & we can look into it. We can only work with the data we get, hence it is always a good idea to make sure the input covers all the scenarios that you expect. That way , you get a robust solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to update the input. I've been trying to catch those people in another dataframe like so: df_notbooked = df_booking.merge(df_actual.drop_duplicates(), on=['IDs','DepartureTime','Destination'], how= 'right', indicator = True)
and getting right only, with no success